# Location.getLatitude etc. keeps changing

Tags: android

I built an GPS tracking app using this online tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html.

Its working fine.

```
    Location.getLatitude()
    Location.getLongitude()
```

However, I noticed that the outputs that I obtained for these 2 methods keeps changing on my app display screen every 5 seconds. Why is that so? Thanks.

Comment: because your location is changing?

Comment: You can control the call by minimum change distance and minimum  duration if you use location provider properly

Answer (score 0):

Did you use:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this); ?
```

However keep in mind that location can change not only in lat e ln but also with accurancy.